# Absolute inequality derivation

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I have been trying to prove an inequality that I am not even sure if it is even true or not. However I am experiencing great difficulties with this proof. I have an intuition that it is true and have been trying to derive it but with no success. 
Here is the following set up:

$0 < x \leq y $

$0 < a \leq b $

From this I am trying to derive the following:

$|y-b|+|x-a| \leq |y-a| + |x-b|$

I have tried 'reverse engineering' and trying to come back to a statement that be easily derived from the initial set up but without success. After this I tried playing around with triangle inequalities but ended doing recursive steps in my solution attempts.

The inequality isn't random but some sort of "intuition" coming from that if we add the difference of the smaller numbers (x,a) to the difference of the bigger numbers (y,b) then this will be smaller than if we just pair them up the other way (y,a) and (x,b). Of course this intuition could be wrong.

Does anyone know if this is true and how would I work to prove it?

Comment: I used Excel to calculate this for 225 quadruples (with x,y <= 5, all numbers integers) and found that this is always true.

Comment: Hint:

There are 6 cases:

$$x\le y\le a\le b$$$$x\le a\le y\le b$$$$a\le x\le y\le b$$$$a\le x\le b\le y$$$$x\le a\le b\le y$$$$a\le b \le x \le y$$

Comment: @hkmather802 That doesn't seem like a hint as much as it does a suggestion to brute force this problem..

Comment: I don't know whether my answer suit your need, but as you see every case only requires little work. Just 6 cases.

Comment: @stantheman I picked up your equation with $a$ and $b$ reversed. I am reworking it.

Comment: Note that the two positivity hypothesis in the post are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove/disprove $|y-b|+|x-a| \leq |y-a| + |x-b|$, we shall consider 6 cases.

These are the cases:

$$x\le y\le a\le b$$$$x\le a\le y\le b$$$$a\le x\le y\le b$$$$a\le x\le b\le y$$$$x\le a\le b\le y$$$$a\le b \le x \le y$$

For Case 1,

$|y-b|+|x-a|=b-y+a-x=(b-x)+(a-y)\le|y-a|+|x-b|$.

For Case 2,

$|y-b|+|x-a|=b-y+a-x=(b-x)+(a-y)=(b-x)-(y-a)\\=(b-x)-|y-a|\le|x-b|+|y-a|$.

May try case 3-6 on your own.

Comment: Think I will give this a try. Initially I did not want to do this thinking there would 4 factorial possibilities, but you reminded me that there is way less due to the initial restrictions. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcomed.

Comment: It worked. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$t\mapsto |t|$ is convex, so Karamata's inequality allows you to conclude from $(y-a, x-b)\succ (y-b, x-a)$.

Comment: What does $\succ$ stand for?

Comment: Majorizes. Look up Karamata's inequality, will post a link later if you have trouble. Essentially the side that majorises is more "spread out", and if the mean is the same, for a convex function that sum will be higher.

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$
D((x, y), (x_0, y_0)) = \lvert x - x_0 \rvert + \lvert y - y_0 \rvert = C
$$
defines a diamond $D$ with diagonal lenght $2C$ centered around $(x_0, y_0)$.

[image: diamonds]

The image gives the diamonds centered around $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ for $C=1$ and $C = 2$. The centers are mirrored along the identity function $y = x$.

- The condition $0 < x \le y$ restricts $(x,y)$ to all points on or
  above id, for positive $x$.
- The condition $0 < a \le b$ restricts the center $(a,b)$ of the first
  diamond to that region as well.

Your inequality

> $|y-b|+|x-a| \leq |y-a| + |x-b|$

can be stated as
$$
D((x,y),(a, b)) \le D((x,y),(b, a)) \quad (*)
$$

If $D$ is interpreted as a distance, it states that someone at $(x,y)$ is either closer to the center $(a, b)$ than to the mirrored center $(b,a)$ or at the same distance to both.

This holds on the considered area.

Answer (score 0):

Wlog, $a\le x\le y,$ so that what we want to prove rewrites
$$|y-b|+x-a\le y-a+|x-b|.$$

It is therefore an immediate consequence of the triangular inequality $$|y-b|\le|y-x|+|x-b|.$$