# Given $A \leq X$ and $B \leq Y$, prove $|A - B| + |X - Y| \leq |A - Y| + |X - B|$

Tags: proof-writing, triangle-inequality

I've been really struggling to prove the following inequality; I'm assuming I'll need to apply the triangle inequality at some point but I can't figure out how to break it down well enough.  The inequality is as follows (we can assume we're just using natural numbers)

Given $A \leq X$ and $B \leq Y$, prove $|A - B| + |X - Y| \leq |A - Y| + |X - B|$

Comment: Speaking more broadly, for any questions of this type, my first line of attack is generally to split the problem into cases, and verify that the assertion holds in each case.  Although elegance is desirable, I give priority to attacking/solving the problem over elegance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting into cases works quite well. Let $S=|A - Y| + |X - B|-(|A - B| + |X - Y|)$ Without loss of generality, we can assume that $A\le B$. There are then $3$ cases:

1. If $A\le X\le B\le Y$, then $S= B-X+Y-A-(Y-X+B-A)=0$.
2. If $A\le B \le X\le Y$, then $S=Y-A+X-B-(Y-X+B-A)=2(X-B)\ge 0$.
3. If $A\le B \le Y \le X$, then $S=Y-A+X-B-(X-Y+B-A)=2(Y-B)\ge 0$.

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Comment: I added [a simpler answer in the older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4770121), of which this one is a duplicate.